# Subtract 3 months to yyyymm month format column hive sql

Tags: date, hive, bigdata, hiveql

In HiveSql I have a yearmonth [yyyymm] column from which I need to subtract 3 months 
For example: if yearmonth is 201912 , the record required is 201909

Can someone please help me with the syntax or script I need to get for this ?

I have tried addmonths, conv(), and reg_extract 
But nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_months()` function works with dates. Convert yyyyMM to `yyyy-MM-01` date, apply `add_months` and format as `yyyyMM` again:

```
with your_table as (select '201912' as yearmonth)

select date_format(add_months(concat_ws('-',substr(yearmonth,1,4),substr(yearmonth,5,2),'01'),-3),'yyyyMM') as yearmonth 
  from your_table;
```

Result:

```
201909
```